# Dredd configuration opposite of --only

Tags: laravel, config, dredd

Does anyone know if there is a possibility to excludes some transaction names while running the `Dredd` test? I know that the `--only` command can be used to define the wanted transactions, but I want the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Dredd's Hooks](https://dredd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/hooks/) and mark some transactions as skipped by setting their `skip` attribute to `true`.

Comment: We used Dredd's Hooks, but we ran into some connection issues in combination with Homestead.

Comment: Connection issues? What exactly? Maybe if you don't mind, can you file an issue on github so we can figure out what's the issue and fix it? Unfortunately there is no other way how to skip some transactions.